# discord.Interactions don't work only in my bot [solved]

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

I was trying to create a button for my discord bot and I had an "interaction error". after I searched the entire Internet in search of a solution, I noticed that my bot basically does not work discord.Interactions
what should I do? could this be related to the transition from `discord.py` on `pycord`?

for example, my button code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import View, Button
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='k.', intents=intents)
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    button = Button(label='button', style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, emoji='')
    async def but_callback(interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("HI!")
    button.callback = but_callback
    view = View()
    view.add_item(button)
    await ctx.send('click me!', view=view)

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: You use discord.Intents.all() but then use intents.message_content..? All intents should be true already. Regardless, your code is fine. This might be an intents issue in the discord app directory portal.

Comment: Can we see the full error? That would be super helpful.

Comment: @BlueRobin there are no errors in the console, the only error is the `interaction failed` error in the discord. I have all intents enabled on the developer's website. I tried to remove `intents.message_content = True` but it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem turned out to be very trivial. after receiving the developer's badge, I did not delete the link to the special site. after the removal, everything worked =|

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Pycord is different from discord.py in a lot of thing. I'll provide you a button example that is 100% working in discord.py. If it will not work for you, I recommand reading the pycord documentation on buttons and interactions.

The code:

```
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Test",style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="my_custom_button")
    async def testbutton(self,interaction:discord.Interaction,button:discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Testing...")

@bot.tree.command(name='testbutton')
async def testbutton(interaction:discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(view=MyView())
```

Also if you want it to work after a bot restart paste this into your `on_ready()` event or a command: `bot.add_view(MyView())`

Comment: Wouldn't this produce an error because it's sending an empty message?

Comment: for note: I tried to put the View in a separate class (as you suggested) and it did not solve the problem (I tried to run both on `pycord` and on `discord.py`) @Rexy

Comment: It is working in discord.py. Is there any errors you have? Have you modified the code to bot.command or synced tree commands? @kot_v_palto

Comment: I have solved the problem. it turned out to be very banal and had nothing to do with the code. @Rexy

Comment: @Rexy I didn't downvote because of the code in particular. I downvoted cause it had nothing to do with the question. If anything, it should've been a comment.

Comment: Well. The problem was with interactions "discord.Interactions don't work" which is solved by my code.

Comment: @Rexy after removing the problematic link, my code worked without any problems